# Файлы выше точки входа

Tags: .htaccess

Собственно вопрос. Можно ли при обращении отдавать файл лежащий уровнем выше точки входа средствами апача?

PS: Нужно это для уменьшения количества телодвижений при подключении модулей CMS. Вся логика лежит уровнем выше точки входа.

Comment: можно..........

Comment: Зачем? Чтоб скрыть файл от прямого доступа? Или у вашего хостинга специфические настройки и вы пытаетесь обойти их?